# Does ExpressJS follow the MVC pattern?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to understand creating a MVC Website With ExpressJS from https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-complete-mvc-website-with-expressjs--net-34168

Does ExpressJS have the MVC pattern? Or does it follow some other pattern, e.g. just "C" without "MV" like Flask?

Comment: I believe it is considerd mvc, theoretically. However, I've noticed that these terms are used a bit loosely. Many times something described as mvc is more accurately mvv pattern etc...

Comment: What is MVV?...

Comment: I meant model view view model. For instance, angularjs is often described as mvc, while it resembles an mvvm pattern more accurately.

Comment: maybe @silencedogood meant M-V-VM (model - viev - viewmodel)

Answer (score 6):

ExpressJs does not follow any specific pattern. You are free to structure your project as you wish.

An official example of a MVC application is here: https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/master/examples/mvc

For more info and examples, see: [ExpressJs Official Docs](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html#how-should-i-structure-my-application)

Comment: Thanks. Is it a minimal or micro framework, just "C
" without "MV", similar to Flask https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547206/flask-framework-mvc-pattern/12547285?

Comment: "Minimal framework" intended as a framework not strictly tied to a predefined logical model (I think of CodeIgniter 2), yes.

Comment: do you mean it isn't tied to "M"? What about "V"?

Comment: Both. You can easily use ExpressJs with your favourite template engine (and then you have to follow the engine conventions) or none of them. 
Obviously, you can have an application without views (eg, an API Rest)